# rich text box value store in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, richtextbox

I have a rich text box with name `placeofstudent1`. I want to store whatever is written in the rich text box in a variable named `Place` so I can pass that info into the database.

```cs
try
    {

        string name = nameofstudent.Text;
        string father = fatherofstudent.Text;
        string mother = motherofstudent.Text;
        string id = stud_id.Text;
        string gender;
        if (male.IsChecked == true)
        {
            gender = "M";
        }
        else
            gender = "F";

        string studentAge = ageofstudent.Text;

        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dob.Text);
        int Age = Convert.ToInt16(ageofstudent.Text);
                   
        string Place = placeofstudent1.Text;
    
        connect();
        con.Open();
    
        string saved = "insert into student_details (student_id,student_name,father_name,mother_name,gender,age,dob,place,class)values('" + id + "', '" + name + "','" + father + "','" + mother + "','" + gender + "','" + Age + "','" + dt + "','" + Place + "','" + x + "')";
    
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(saved, con);
    
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
    
        con.Close();
```

If I try to fill the variable `Place` using `.Text`, It doesn't work. What method can I use to make this possible? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are using the wrong control. Currently you are using the WinForms control and not the WPF control. Do you expect rich text content? I doubt it. For name and other person related data you don't use formatted text. Use a  normal TextBox instead, which is more lightweight and easier to handle.

Comment: I have been informed to use rich text box which is why I am using it. Also, I want to learn how to use it in general.

Comment: This is the correct [`System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox?view=netcore-3.1) (note the different namespace). You will notice that it doesn't have a `Text` property. You have to manually convert the content (`RichTextBox.Document`, which is a [`FlowDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument?view=netcore-3.1)) to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong control. Currently you are using the WinForms control and not the WPF control.

This is the correct [`System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox?view=netcore-3.1) (note the different namespace). You will notice that the WPF implementation doesn't have a `Text` property but a `Document` property.
You have to manually convert the content (`RichTextBox.Document`, which is a [`FlowDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument?view=netcore-3.1)) to a string.

```
<Window>
  <RichTextBox x:Name="MyRichTextBox" />
</Window>


var richTextBoxContentRange = new TextRange(
  this.MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, 
  this.MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

string richTextBoxText = richTextBoxContentRange.Text;
```

Comment: I tried finding the System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox in my references but I am not able to.

Comment: Do you have XAML code? Are you sure that you are working on a WPF project? Is your view a Window or a Form? Can you show your view please?

Comment: I am using WPF and my view is window. Im not sure how to show my view ^^'

Comment: But then you MUST be able to use the control. All framework controls are available by default. I just asked you to show your XAML code. I had the feeling you are targeting the wrong framework. First remove all WinForms references from your project. If it still doesn't work, create a new project or Window file and start from there.